# jQuery Placeholder & Master Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net, placeholder

I'm using the jQuery Placeholder plugin on my forms, everything works perfectly on the asp.net page; and on my masterpage I have all the correct .ClientID settings so my jQuery Validation is works.

The issue I am having is that to initialise the placeholder script you use:

```
$('input, textarea').placeholder();
```

Is there a way for me to get this working on a masterpage, I tried calling

```
<%=txtFirstName.UniqueID %>.placeholder()
```

with no luck, is there a way to get this working?

**Sorry guys I made a mistake; the placeholder is on a TextBox.**

All help is greatly appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>I can only imagine that your `ddlFirstHome.UniqueID` attribute returns a string with the ID of the element you want to add a placeholder to. Something like `FirstHome`. So you would need to select it with jQuery...</strike>

```
$("#FirstHome").placeholder();
```

Adding in the ASP.NET placeholder you get...

```
$("#<%=ddlFirstHome.UniqueID %>").placeholder();
```

**EDIT** Forget the above, you should be able to run the plugin on all inputs and textareas indiscriminately. Presumably in your master page you have a html head tag or you are including it in your template somewhere. Just add...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Run on document ready
  $(function() {
    // target all inputs and textareas with the attribute placeholder
    // and enable cross-browser placeholders
    $("input[placeholder],textarea[placeholder]").placeholder();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work; I dont think that .placeholder() works by setting the placeholder for a specific control, I think it just loops thought the control tree.

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly.

Thank you so much mate.

I think I need to dig a little deeper inside of placeholder.js to find out how it actually works!

Comment: It's likely if you weren't wrapping it in a document ready function that the inputs and textareas simply didn't exist at the point you were running the function. Instead it would have run the script placeholder function found no inputs or textareas and continued loading the rest of the page. The document ready function tells it to wait until the rest of the document is loaded before running the rest of the script.

Answer (score 1):

Modified code: try this

```
$("#<%=ddlFirstHome.UniqueID %>").placeholder()
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#<%= dllFirstHome.UniqueID %>").placeholder();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
$('#<%=ddlFirstHome.UniqueID %>').placeholder();
```